# IntentService abruptly stopping

Tags: android, android-service, intentservice

I have a slightly puzzling problem and I assume that it would be a easy fix due to a stupid oversight.

My main task is to upload files of images and audio recordings on to a location on my server. I do this via FTP.

1. Activity calls service via startService(intentName);
2. onHandleIntent() creates a new thread.
3. In the new thread, the files which needs to be uploaded are put into a ListArray
4. Loop through the listArray. In this loop, pass the file name to the FTP server. If it is successfully added, I add this file name to another ListArray that contains confirmed name files.
5. After the loop is complete, I stop the service by calling stopSelf()
6. I create a notification to notify the user that the service is complete.

I am having a problem with step 4. 
The loop only uploads two of my files and then stops abruptly. While the second file is being uploaded, the phone goes into sleep mode. There is no notification.

I have tried the following

- I originally used AsyncTask but this never managed to upload all the listed files in one go.
- Used StrictMode.
- Created a second class that was a service instead of an IntentService.
- Tried startForeground() - However this is not an option as this will kill my UI and I get the app not responding popup.

Can someone please suggest a way forward? 
Here is my code

This is the code in the MainActivity.class

```
    Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UploadMedia.class);
    service.putExtra("imageFileName", "/Folder/uploadtheseimagefiles.txt");
    service.putExtra("audioFileName", "/Folder/uploadtheseaudiofiles.txt");
    startService(service);
```

Here is my code for the IntentService

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    final String imageFileName = intent.getStringExtra("imageFileName");
    final String audioFileName = intent.getStringExtra("audioFileName");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String serverAddress = "server address here";
            String userID = "user name here";
            String password = "password here";
            ArrayList<String> confirmed = new ArrayList<String>();

            //1. Upload the image files
            if (imageFileName.length() != 0) {
                File uploadContents = new File(imageFileName);
                if (uploadContents.exists()) {
                    try {
                        //Read the entries to be uploaded
                        InputStream ststr = new FileInputStream(uploadContents);
                        BufferedReader stbr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ststr));
                        String line = "";
                        upData.clear();
                        while ((line  = stbr.readLine ()) != null) {
                            upData.add(line.trim());
                        }
                        stbr.close();
                        ststr.close();

                        //Upload the entries
                        confirmed.clear();
                        for(int i = 0; i < upData.size(); i++) {
                            if (new UploadViaFTP().ftpUpload(upData.get(i).toString(), serverAddress, userID, password)) {
                                confirmed.add(upData.get(i).toString());
                            }
                        }

                        //Check the uploaded filenames against the ones that were to be uploaded.
                        ArrayList<String> remaining = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < upData.size(); i++) {
                            if (!confirmed.contains(upData.get(i)))
                                remaining.add(upData.get(i));
                        }

                        //If there are any remaining, write them back into the file.
                        if (remaining.size() != 0) {
                            try {
                                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(imageFileName);
                                for (int i = 0; i < remaining.size(); i++) {
                                    fw.write(remaining.get(i));
                                    fw.append("\n");
                                }
                                fw.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        } else { //All files have been uploaded
                            File delFile = new File(imageFileName);
                            if (delFile.exists())
                                delFile.delete();
                        }   
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            //2. Upload the audio files
            if (audioFileName.length() != 0) {
                File uploadContents = new File(audioFileName);
                if (uploadContents.exists()) {
                    try {
                        //Read the entries to be uploaded
                        InputStream ststr = new FileInputStream(uploadContents);
                        BufferedReader stbr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ststr));
                        String line = "";
                        upData.clear();
                        while ((line  = stbr.readLine ()) != null) {
                            upData.add(line.trim());
                        }
                        stbr.close();
                        ststr.close();

                        //Upload the entries
                        confirmed.clear();
                        for(int i = 0; i < upData.size(); i++) {
                            if (new UploadViaFTP().ftpUpload(upData.get(i).toString(), serverAddress, userID, password)) {
                                confirmed.add(upData.get(i).toString());
                            }
                        }

                        //Check the uploaded filenames against the ones that were to be uploaded.
                        ArrayList<String> remaining = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < upData.size(); i++) {
                            if (!confirmed.contains(upData.get(i)))
                                remaining.add(upData.get(i));
                        }

                        //If there are any remaining, write them back into the file.
                        if (remaining.size() != 0) {
                            try {
                                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(audioFileName);
                                for (int i = 0; i < remaining.size(); i++) {
                                    fw.write(remaining.get(i));
                                    fw.append("\n");
                                }
                                fw.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        } else { //All files have been uploaded
                            File delFile = new File(audioFileName);
                            if (delFile.exists())
                                delFile.delete();
                        }   
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            stopSelf();

            //Final check before notification. 
            File checkFile = new File("/Folder/uploadtheseimagefiles.txt");
            if (!checkFile.exists()) {
                checkFile = new File("/Folder/uploadtheseaudiofiles.txt");
                if (!checkFile.exists()) {
                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                         .setContentTitle("Something")
                         .setContentText("Uploading of media complete.");
                    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                   PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                   builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

                   // Add as notification
                   NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(getApplication().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                   manager.notify(0, builder.build());
                }
            }               
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Manifest.xml file

```
    <service
        android:name=".UploadMedia"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true"/>
```

New info: 
The failure always happens at the second file according to my test case. First image size is about 900KB and the second one is about 2MB. 
On debugging, I am not able to get the status of FTPUpload of the second file. But the debugger stops for the first file and I am able to proceed.

New info: Part 2: 
It might be relevant. I am using an asynctask to update some data to a DB on my server. Once successfully returned, it collates all the files names that needs to be uploaded. This collated data is what I am passing in my Intent to the service.

Also another confession. I have this exact process running and working in another app of mine. Data upload to a DB using an asynctask. on the post execution method, it calls the service to upload the data to the FTP server. I have compared the manifest file, the service and the call to the service and everything seems to be the same.

New Info: Part 3:
The LOG file

```
02-12 10:03:40.521: I/PERSONAL(14962): Calling the service
02-12 10:03:40.525: W/Binder_1(791): type=1400 audit(0.0:20440): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[743779]" dev="sockfs" ino=743779 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
02-12 10:03:40.525: W/Binder_1(791): type=1400 audit(0.0:20441): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[743779]" dev="sockfs" ino=743779 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
02-12 10:03:40.534: I/PERSONAL(14962): Uploading audio file 0
02-12 10:03:40.585: V/RenderScript(14962): 0xb397e000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
02-12 10:03:42.278: I/Finsky(14117): [3310] com.google.android.finsky.d.e.run(1151): Replicating app states via AMAS.
02-12 10:03:42.398: I/Finsky(14117): [3310] com.google.android.finsky.d.c.a(313): Completed 0 account content syncs with 0 successful.
02-12 10:03:42.400: I/Finsky(14117): [1] com.google.android.finsky.services.j.a(148): Installation state replication succeeded.
02-12 10:03:42.434: I/PERSONAL(14962): Uploading audio file 1
02-12 10:03:42.515: W/Binder_F(1876): type=1400 audit(0.0:20442): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[743796]" dev="sockfs" ino=743796 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
02-12 10:03:42.515: W/Binder_F(1876): type=1400 audit(0.0:20443): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[743796]" dev="sockfs" ino=743796 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
02-12 10:03:43.400: D/audio_hw_primary(201): disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
02-12 10:03:43.400: D/audio_hw_primary(201): disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
02-12 10:03:44.222: I/PERSONAL(14962): Uploading image file 0
02-12 10:03:44.565: W/Binder_5(1372): type=1400 audit(0.0:20444): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[745643]" dev="sockfs" ino=745643 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
02-12 10:03:44.565: W/Binder_5(1372): type=1400 audit(0.0:20445): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[745643]" dev="sockfs" ino=745643 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
02-12 10:03:46.535: W/Binder_4(1220): type=1400 audit(0.0:20446): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[745654]" dev="sockfs" ino=745654 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
02-12 10:03:46.535: W/Binder_4(1220): type=1400 audit(0.0:20447): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[745654]" dev="sockfs" ino=745654 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
02-12 10:03:59.995: W/Binder_6(1388): type=1400 audit(0.0:20448): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[743809]" dev="sockfs" ino=743809 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
02-12 10:03:59.995: W/Binder_6(1388): type=1400 audit(0.0:20449): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[743809]" dev="sockfs" ino=743809 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
02-12 10:04:04.787: I/DeviceStateChecker(1718): screenOn: true, isCharging: true
02-12 10:04:29.560: D/NetlinkSocketObserver(781): NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=152656259, fe80::86c9:b2ff:fe6c:5ce9, [84C9B26C5CE9], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_PROBE}
02-12 10:04:29.705: I/PlayCommon(14117): [3292] com.google.android.play.a.g.e(909): Preparing logs for uploading
02-12 10:04:29.733: I/PlayCommon(14117): [3292] com.google.android.play.a.g.a(1049): Connecting to server: https://play.googleapis.com/play/log?format=raw&proto_v2=true
02-12 10:04:29.901: I/PERSONAL(14962): Uploading image file 1
02-12 10:04:29.971: I/PlayCommon(14117): [3315] com.google.android.play.a.g.e(909): Preparing logs for uploading
02-12 10:04:29.972: I/PlayCommon(14117): [3315] com.google.android.play.a.g.e(911): No file ready to send
02-12 10:04:31.635: I/PlayCommon(14117): [3292] com.google.android.play.a.g.a(1127): Successfully uploaded logs.
02-12 10:04:46.450: D/NetlinkSocketObserver(781): NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=152673149, fe80::86c9:b2ff:fe6c:5ce9, [84C9B26C5CE9], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_STALE}
02-12 10:04:58.348: V/GsmInboundSmsHandler(1549): Unable to find carrier package: [], nor systemPackages: []
02-12 10:04:58.363: D/MmsService(1549): getAutoPersisting
02-12 10:04:58.377: I/ActivityManager(781): Start proc 15147:com.google.android.talk/u0a27 for broadcast com.google.android.talk/com.google.android.apps.hangouts.sms.SmsDeliverReceiver
02-12 10:04:59.064: D/BabelGcmRegistration(15147): GcmRegistration: Checking GCM registration
02-12 10:04:59.079: I/Babel_telephony(15147): TeleModule.onApplicationCreate
02-12 10:04:59.089: I/Babel_SMS(15147): MmsConfig: mnc/mcc: 404/86
02-12 10:04:59.090: I/Babel_SMS(15147): MmsConfig.loadMmsSettings
02-12 10:04:59.091: I/Babel_SMS(15147): MmsConfig.loadDeviceMmsSettings from API: userAgent=Nexus5, uaProfUrl=http://gsm.lge.com/html/gsm/Nexus5-M3.xml
02-12 10:04:59.091: I/Babel_SMS(15147): MmsConfig.loadFromDatabase
02-12 10:04:59.105: E/SQLiteLog(15147): (1) no such table: mmsconfig
02-12 10:04:59.107: I/Babel_SMS(15147): MmsConfig: no mmsconfig table android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: mmsconfig (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT key, value, type FROM mmsconfig WHERE numeric=?
02-12 10:04:59.107: I/Babel_SMS(15147): MmsConfig.loadFromResources
02-12 10:04:59.118: I/Babel_Prime(15147): wrapCrashReportingIntoUncaughtExceptionHandler
02-12 10:04:59.119: E/Babel_SMS(15147): canonicalizeMccMnc: invalid mccmnc nullnull
02-12 10:04:59.121: I/Babel_SMS(15147): MmsConfig.loadMmsSettings: userAgent=Nexus5, uaProfUrl=http://gsm.lge.com/html/gsm/Nexus5-M3.xml
02-12 10:04:59.126: I/Babel_App(15147): Startup - clean
02-12 10:04:59.128: I/Babel_SMS(15147): ApnsOta: OTA version -1
02-12 10:04:59.134: I/Babel(15147): Invalid account: 3 isEmptyName: true nameEqualsGaiaId: false
02-12 10:04:59.169: I/Babel_Prime(15147): isMemoryEnabled=false
02-12 10:04:59.169: I/Babel_Prime(15147): isTimerEnabled=false
02-12 10:04:59.169: I/Babel_Prime(15147): isCrashCounterEnabled=true
02-12 10:04:59.170: I/Babel_Prime(15147): primesPackageConfigurationsProvider=false
02-12 10:04:59.172: I/Babel(15147): Deleting: false for 3
02-12 10:04:59.174: I/Babel_Prime(15147): startMemoryMonitor
02-12 10:04:59.233: D/Babel(15147): created account premthomas@gmail.com => Redacted-20-chars
02-12 10:04:59.263: W/FortumoInApp(5700): Broadcast is disabled, there is no sense, to countinue.
02-12 10:04:59.274: I/Babel_ConcService(15147): Binding ConcurrentService
02-12 10:04:59.280: I/ActivityManager(781): Killing 13354:com.android.settings/1000 (adj 15): empty #17
02-12 10:04:59.341: D/ActivityManager(781): cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 13354
02-12 10:04:59.367: I/Babel_ConcService(15147): Acquired partial wake lock to keep ConcurrentService alive
02-12 10:04:59.514: W/IcingInternalCorpora(1644): getNumBytesRead when not calculated.
02-12 10:04:59.518: I/Icing(1644): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
02-12 10:04:59.672: W/linker(15147): /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/arm/libgmscore.so: unused DT entry: type 0x7ffffffd arg 0x795
02-12 10:04:59.689: W/linker(15147): /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/arm/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0xe0
02-12 10:04:59.689: W/linker(15147): /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/arm/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so: unused DT entry: type 0x7ffffffd arg 0x1cb
02-12 10:04:59.697: V/JNIHelp(15147): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 242 native methods...
02-12 10:04:59.712: I/art(15147): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLExtendedSessionImpl>
02-12 10:04:59.713: I/art(15147): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLExtendedSessionImpl>
02-12 10:04:59.768: I/ProviderInstaller(15147): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
02-12 10:04:59.823: W/VideoCapabilities(15147): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
02-12 10:04:59.848: I/VideoCapabilities(15147): Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
02-12 10:04:59.858: W/VideoCapabilities(15147): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
02-12 10:04:59.859: W/VideoCapabilities(15147): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
02-12 10:04:59.862: W/VideoCapabilities(15147): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
02-12 10:04:59.927: D/NuPlayerDriver(201): reset(0xb3876600)
02-12 10:04:59.927: D/NuPlayerDriver(201): notifyListener_l(0xb3876600), (8, 0, 0)
02-12 10:04:59.927: D/NuPlayerDriver(201): notifyResetComplete(0xb3876600)
02-12 10:04:59.942: I/Babel_ConcService(15147): Released partial wake lock as ConcurrentService became idle
02-12 10:05:00.041: D/NuPlayerDriver(201): notifyListener_l(0xb34b8720), (1, 0, 0)
02-12 10:05:00.041: D/MediaPlayer(921): setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
02-12 10:05:00.044: I/MediaFocusControl(781):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@dd2779c req=3flags=0x0
02-12 10:05:00.045: D/NuPlayerDriver(201): start(0xb34b8720), state is 4, eos is 0
02-12 10:05:00.045: I/GenericSource(201): start
02-12 10:05:00.053: E/OMXNodeInstance(201): setConfig(103:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigPriority(0x6f800002)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
02-12 10:05:00.053: I/ACodec(201): codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
02-12 10:05:00.054: I/MediaCodec(201): MediaCodec will operate in async mode
02-12 10:05:00.060: D/Babel_RtcImpressions(15147): Type: 1926
02-12 10:05:00.072: D/PhoneStatusBar(921): disable: < expand ICONS* alerts SYSTEM_INFO* back home recent clock search quick_settings >
02-12 10:05:00.075: D/audio_hw_primary(201): out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
02-12 10:05:00.087: D/NuPlayerDriver(201): notifyListener_l(0xb34b8720), (6, 0, 0)
02-12 10:05:00.096: D/audio_hw_primary(201): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: none)
02-12 10:05:00.096: D/msm8974_platform(201): platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2) acdb_id(15)
02-12 10:05:00.096: D/audio_hw_primary(201): enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
02-12 10:05:00.099: D/audio_hw_primary(201): enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
02-12 10:05:00.122: D/CountryDetector(781): The first listener is added
02-12 10:05:00.639: I/Babel(15147): connection state changed from UNKNOWN to CONNECTED
02-12 10:05:00.869: I/NuPlayerDecoder(201): [audio] saw output EOS
02-12 10:05:01.271: D/NuPlayerDriver(201): notifyListener_l(0xb34b8720), (2, 0, 0)
02-12 10:05:01.271: I/MediaFocusControl(781):  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@dd2779c
02-12 10:05:04.252: D/audio_hw_primary(201): disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
02-12 10:05:04.253: D/audio_hw_primary(201): disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
02-12 10:05:04.883: W/IcingInternalCorpora(1644): getNumBytesRead when not calculated.
02-12 10:05:04.915: I/Icing(1644): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
02-12 10:05:05.932: I/Icing(1644): Indexing D2350FC178F0C3C6D9357237E165CCBC64772E44 from com.google.android.gms
02-12 10:05:06.040: I/Icing(1644): Indexing done D2350FC178F0C3C6D9357237E165CCBC64772E44
02-12 10:05:06.057: D/PhoneStatusBar(921): disable: < expand icons* alerts system_info* back home recent clock search quick_settings >
02-12 10:05:14.171: I/Babel_ConcService(15147): Acquired partial wake lock to keep ConcurrentService alive
02-12 10:05:14.182: I/Babel_ConcService(15147): Released partial wake lock as ConcurrentService became idle
02-12 10:05:18.751: I/ProcessStatsService(781): Prepared write state in 3ms
02-12 10:05:18.753: I/ProcessStatsService(781): Prepared write state in 2ms
02-12 10:05:29.137: I/Telecom(781): PhoneAccountRegistrar: SimCallManager queried, returning: null
02-12 10:05:29.143: I/Babel_telephony(15147): TeleModule.updateConnectionManagerRegistration, registration preference changed from false to false
02-12 10:05:29.143: W/Babel(15147): BAM#gBA: invalid account id: -1
02-12 10:05:29.144: W/Babel(15147): BAM#gBA: invalid account id: -1
02-12 10:05:29.144: I/Babel_telephony(15147): TeleModule.updateIncomingCallRegistration, preferred account for incoming calls changed from: null to null
02-12 10:05:29.151: I/Telecom(781): PhoneAccountRegistrar: SimCallManager queried, returning: null
02-12 10:05:49.090: I/PowerManagerService(781): Going to sleep due to screen timeout (uid 1000)...
02-12 10:05:49.175: W/Binder_3(958): type=1400 audit(0.0:20450): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[743742]" dev="sockfs" ino=743742 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
02-12 10:05:49.175: W/Binder_3(958): type=1400 audit(0.0:20451): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[743742]" dev="sockfs" ino=743742 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
02-12 10:05:49.091: I/PowerManagerService(781): Sleeping (uid 1000)...
02-12 10:05:49.665: V/KeyguardServiceDelegate(781): onScreenTurnedOff()
```

I will take ANY suggestions / questions.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a new thread in `onHandleIndent` ?  This method is already called from a background thread and hence it's already not gonna hamper your UI rendering or something. Just run your logic directly in the `onHandleIntent` method. Give it a try

Comment: Thanks Dibzmania. I was wondering why I didn't do that in the first place and changed my code as per your suggestion. However post execution I realized why. I get the android.View.WindowLeaked error. Addition information added to the end of my question.

Comment: After extensive changes, the behavior of the changes you mentioned had no effect on the output. There are still only the first two files being uploaded. What would you suggest next?

Comment: Do you get anything on the logcat ? When you say it stops abruptly, there should be some log. Are you sure there is no issue with the upload process ?  Irrespective of whatever result you get, you should not ideally start a new thread in intent service

Comment: Hey Dibzmania. I've checked the log cat as per your instructions and introduced a couple of log cat messages at at couple of points. I filtered them by the application name and I got nothing. I see that the service has started, the smaller audio files go in first and then the larger image file. Image files 1 and 2 starts and I see them on my FTP server. And then it stops. No messages.There are a couple of messages that caught my eye. BINDER type 1400 avc denied. And ConnectivityService: notify CAP_CHANGED. Could this be a clue?

Comment: Can you pull out the complete logcat log and put it here for analysis. Just a line here and there can't help. Also you mentioned about another app where you are doing the exact same thing. Is it working over there ?

Comment: I have pulled out as much as I could. Hope it helps.Yes. Its still working in the other app. I just passed about 4 image files there, a total size of over 6 MB.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call stopSelf() as IntentService stops itself when there are no requests in the queue to serve.

Add more logs statement to find out why it is reaching to stopSelf before uploading all the file.